# Join on duplicate values

Tags: php, mysql

I am having two tables:

- `Question (question_id, std_div_sub_id, question, level)`
- `answer (Ans_id, question_id, answer,  iscorrect,
  correct_mrk,negative_mrk)`

for multiple answer question and setting iscorrect as 1 for correct answer and i am using following query:

```
select * from question join answer
  on answer.question_id = question.question_id
  where question.type='$qtype' 
    and question.std_div_sub_id='$std_div_sub_val';
```

and getting duplicate values for questions but I want only distinct question with all its answers.

Comment: So you want to find all answers by all users for a particular question?

Comment: That's how left join works. If you want to get all answers for every question, you will have duplicate question data for every joined answer.

Comment: @Desolator Sir yes I want all answers by all users for a particular question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
function get_answers($input_question_id)
{
    $sql = <<<_END
    SELECT Ans_id, a.question_id, answer, iscorrect, correct_mrk,negative_mrk
    FROM answer a, question q
    WHERE a.question_id = q.question_id AND a.question_id = $input_question_id
        AND q.type='$qtype' 
        and q.std_div_sub_id='$std_div_sub_val';
_END;
    return mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Notice that you need to input `$input_question_id`, the id of the "particular question" to find all answers of it. 
To find all questions answers, you need to iterate over all `question` rows, passing the function each time the id:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT question_id FROM question");
$len = mysql_row_count($result);
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i)
{
    $question_id = mysql_result($result, $i, 0);
    $ans = get_answers($id); // answers to the current question
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT` to get distinct values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FROM question JOIN answer    
ON answer.question_id = question.question_id    
WHERE question.type='$qtype'    
AND question.std_div_sub_id='$std_div_sub_val';
```

Comment: This will not produce distinct question values

Answer (score 0):

```
You should use the following query with inner join.

select distinct from question
  inner join answer  on answer.question_id = question.question_id
  where question.type='$qtype' 
    and question.std_div_sub_id='$std_div_sub_val';
```

Comment: sir there is error: _You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) from question inner join answer on answer.question_id = question.question_id'_

Comment: Dhaval i have edited answer actually you have to select distinct row with inner join. you will get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you need to do 2 querys.

One for question and other with all the answers.
With a `JOIN` statement you always get one question per answer (If you have 3 answers, return the same 3 question).

Try doing for every question:

```
"SELECT * FROM answer WHERE question_id = ". $question_id;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't get the question one times if you are using a join. You get the question for every answer.
So if a question have 5 answers, you get 5 rows with five times the same question and each answer.
If you have duplicates in answers. You can shrink the the result per DISTINCT

SELECT DISTINCT ...